# Comparing NULL values with empty string in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, view, null

I've 2 tables namely table_1 and table_2. table_1 has the following details

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| id   | col_1  | col_2 | col_3  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
|  100 | red    |       | yellow |
|  101 |        | black | white  |
|  102 | orange | black | white  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

table_2 has the following details

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3  |
+-------+-------+--------+
| red   | NULL  | yellow |
| NULL  | black | white  |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Now, how do I find out the ids of the table_1 which have the entries in the table_2. In the above example, I need to get answers as 100 and 101.

I tried out couple of join queries with this 2 tables, but the problem was equating the NULL and empty string in the queries. Is there a way to equate them? Or can I use views to convert the table_1 empty string to NULL and compare the view and table_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 
   ON COALESCE(t1.col1, '') = COALESCE(t2.col1, '') AND
      COALESCE(t1.col2, '') = COALESCE(t2.col2, '') AND
      COALESCE(t1.col3, '') = COALESCE(t2.col3, '')
```

Comment: A small doubt though, If the column was an integer field and has 0 instead of NULL. Will I be able to use this function to convert 0 to NULL so that I can compare this with another table's column that has some NULL values instead of 0?

Comment: @SamuelRobert You can either use `COALESCE(col, 0)` to convert `NULL` to `0`, or `NULLIF(col, 0)` to convert `0` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate your help :-)